# Is there any other way of getting a function from this piece of code?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I have this pseudocode

```
function mysterious(N):
    count = 0
    for i = 0 to N:
        if (i mod 3 == 0):
            count = count + i
    return count
```

The problem ask for the expression that returns this function using N or in terms of N

The best I have done is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i \bmod 3$

Is there any better way to express the function of this code?
I know the code returns the sum of the numbers divisible by 3

Comment: Your expression is unclear. What is $X_i$? Also, I don't see any reasonable interpretation under which it expresses the value of the function.

Comment: _I know the code returns the sum of the numbers divisible by 3_,  I am not sure about that. You have "return count;" in your code. What is count?

Comment: Yes my expression is unclear, I mean X is just i, I already edited it, and count is the sum of the number divisible by 3

Comment: Please don't use images for code; use the code markdown instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the formula
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k i = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}. $$
You can consider first the case that $N$ is a multiple of $3$.

Further hint: Use the formula
$$ \sum_{i=1}^k 3i = 3\frac{k(k+1)}{2}. $$
When $N$ is a multiple of $3$, a good choice of $k$ is $N/3$. More generally, you should choose $k = \lfloor N/3 \rfloor$.

Comment: I still do not understand the problem ask for a function in terms of n, I do not know how to do it, the hint formula just add 2, 3, 4, 5 and so on, can you elaborate more thanks for answering

Comment: Well, I suggest you keep thinking.

Comment: Ok, thanks , I am struggling with this problem, and It is not homework do you know where can I find related problems with solutions?

Comment: I clarified my answer. I won't give any details beyond that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, although I have to think more because I have not practiced these kind of questions, do you know a good resource for getting better at this kind of math questions?

Comment: You could pick up a discrete math textbook. This is the closest subject I can think of.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it simply the sum of all the multiples of 3 in the range `(0,N)`

It is the sum `3 + 6 + 9 + 12 + ... + int(N/3)`. You can work around from here, following @Yuval answer.

Comment: Actually the first summand is $0$ (though this doesn't affect the final result).